# In Mantis BT -> Repositories -> Manage, when i did "Import Latest Data", files are not getting updated

Tags: gitlab, mantis

I am using GitLab integrated with Mantis BT. In Mantis BT -> Repositories -> Manage, when i did "Import Latest Data", "Files" are not getting updated but "Changesets" and "Issues" are getting updated. Can someone please help me in knowing what may be the issue for files not getting updated

Comment: Hima, please improve your existing questions instead of starting new ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the issue for files in Mantis BT -> Repositories not getting updated when i am doing Import Latest Data in Mantis BT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746258/what-is-the-issue-for-files-in-mantis-bt-repositories-not-getting-updated-whe)